# validation message getting added two times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding the error message div dynamically from jQuery, but the error message is getting added two times even if I am checking the condition isn't working .

below my code :

```js
$('.refEmail').on('focusout', function() {
  var reg = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@@"]+)*)|(".+"))@@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if ($(this).val() != "" && !$(this).val().match(reg)) {

    if ($(this).next(".validation").length == 0) // only add if not added
    {
      $(this).after("<div class='validation' style='color:red;margin-bottom: 20px;'>Please enter valid email</div>");
    }
  } else {
    $(this).next(".validation").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="refEmail" id="ReferralEmail" name="ReferralEmail" type="text" value="">
```

[image: error]

Comment: Can you try with `on('blur', ..` instead of `on('focusout', ...)` ? Also do you have several elements with `class="refEmail"` ?

Comment: yes there are 5 textbox with that class

Comment: edited ! , seems work fine , post whole code to reproduce the problem

Comment: In this snippet it works properly. You need to post an example which actually demonstrates the problem, otherwise we can't help you.